# Hide posts from index page

Tags: jquery, css, hide, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am trying to hide #old from the index page of my blog. I still want to see the posts when I search for them.

I have followed sorrism's [tutorial](https://sorrism.tumblr.com/post/162316792555/tutorial-hiding-posts-with-a-tag-from-the-index) on how to hide tags from the index page. I'm wondering why it's not working properly? I have also tried Chloe's [tutorial](https://bychloethemes.tumblr.com/post/124069523514/how-to-hide-posts-from-your-blog-depending-on-tags) only to end up with this [result](https://66.media.tumblr.com/2200aa320f9d8b892f92af44f0a48d05/e81f461bbcac4fc2-31/s400x600/d73b1c8f2bd6f8b15c5fc410eb6f521d53eb976c.png) if I have it show up *nowhere* on my blog. I tried the latter css code on Chloe's tutorial but everything looks as if no tags are hidden.

```
{block:IndexPage}.hide-old {display:none;}{/block:IndexPage}</style>
<body><article class="posts hide-{TagsAsClasses}">blah blah</article><script 
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
switch(window.location.pathname) {
    case "/tagged/old":
    $('article').removeClass('hide-old');
    break;
} 
});
 </script></body>
```

https://pastebin.com/FX1QJH5X (Result from sorrism's tutorial)

```
.old {
display:none;
padding:10px!important;
width:450px!important;
} </style>
<body>
   <div class="posts{block:IndexPage}{TagsAsClasses}{/block:IndexPage}">
```

https://pastebin.com/Hh3gDAaM (Result from Chloe's tutorial)

Comment: Can you post a link to your tumblr. It's a it tricky to see what is going on here. It looks like you are are setting `.hide-old {display:none}` as well as `hide-{TagsAsClasses}` which will presumably also pass in hide-old if it exists and then your jQuery is attempting to remove that class name. Also `<div class="posts{block:IndexPage}{TagsAsClasses}{/block:IndexPage}">` will concatenate classnames `postshide-old` as there is no space between the tumblr blocks. In addition `{block:indexPage}` is not just the home page, it refers to any index type page.

Comment: My tumblr is https://byrdy.tumblr.com/.

Comment: I'm still doing some digging but on this post: https://byrdy.tumblr.com/post/179770158829/captainswanaremarried-assassinwolffreak189 you have the following class names `posts hide-to_delete_later  old  reblog` this means the class `hide-old` never exists. I think you need a specific tag, and don't use the concatenation method, something like posts with `indexHide`. The way I would do it is to actually pass a class name to the home page. I will post a link later as I have written answers on that which should be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is how I would skin it.

Add this piece of javascript to the bottom of your template.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   const addHTMLClass = function() {
      const doc = $('html');
      const primaryDir = document.location.pathname.split('/')[1]; // get the first directory
      if(!primaryDir) { // if there is no primary directory we should be on the home page right?
         doc.addClass('indexPage'); // add a unique classname to the home page only
      }
   }();
});
```

Then some simple css:

```
.indexPage .hide-old { // or add your own tag/class name here
    display: none;
}
```

For the `.hide-old` class you can use any classname you want but it needs to be a tag on those posts you wish to hide, but not using the tumblr concatenation method, as this may pass through unpredictable class names.

I think this does everything you need, it is not perfect as there are some edge cases which might fail but it's definitely a start.